# How can I put a Tkinter entry inside an SQLite database?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, tkinter

Here is the code for my database

```
# database code
with sqlite3.connect("password_vault.db") as db:
cursor = db.cursor()
# creates a table for masterpassword if one doesn't already exist
cursor.execute("""
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS masterpassword(
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
password TEXT NOT NULL,
email TEXT NOT NULL);
""")
```

I would like to store the entry from this TKinter python code within email, how would I do this?

```
# user input of email
txt3 = Entry(window, width=20)
txt3.pack()
txt3.focus()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create 3 entries each for each column in your database. Lets assume those are `txt1`, `txt2` and `txt3`. Here is how you will insert it:

```py
def push():
    with sqlite3.connect("password_vault.db") as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        sql_command = 'INSERT INTO masterpassword VALUES (?,?,?)' # Query
        values = txt1.get(),txt2.get(),txt3.get() # tuple of values
        cursor.execute(sql_command,values) # Execute the query substituting the values
```

Here, `?` is a placeholder and you will later substitute the values instead of that in the `execute` method. Take a stroll down [here](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-python/insert/)

There are alot of things to note here:

- Id column requires to have unique value, so its not best practice to actually ask the user for id or even you creating one, instead you can use `AUTOINCREMENT`, like `id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,...`. Take proper read [here](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html).
- You shouldn't just insert the password into a database, you should first hash it and then insert it, or else a simple database query by anyone can get you all the passwords easily. [Here](https://github.com/nihaalnz/PassLost) is a similar project I worked on if your looking for ideas(it is not *perfected* yet).

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a submit button that gets the value from the Entry fields and insert it into the database

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3
import random
window = Tk()

width = window.winfo_screenwidth()
height = window.winfo_screenheight()
window.geometry(f"{width}x{height}")


email = StringVar()
password = StringVar()

def submit():

    con = sqlite3.connect('password_vault.db')
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute(f"insert into masterpassword values ({random.randint(1, 101)},'{password.get()}','{email.get()}')")
    con.commit()
    con.close()


# database code
with sqlite3.connect("password_vault.db") as db:
    cursor = db.cursor()
    # creates a table for masterpassword if one doesn't already exist
    cursor.execute("""
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS masterpassword(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    password TEXT NOT NULL,
    email TEXT NOT NULL);
    """)

# user input of email
txt3 = Entry(window, width=20,textvariable=email)
txt3.pack()
txt3.focus()

Password_field = Entry(window,textvariable=password)
Password_field.pack()

submit_button = Button(window,text='Submit',command = submit)
submit_button.pack()


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think there is no guarantee that `random.randint(1, 101)` wont return same number twice over the span of the database

Comment: Use `NULL` instead of random number.

Comment: import uuid 
id = uuid.uuid1() can be used to generate unique id